# Infopath 2013 -

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

I am creating a form on Infopath and will publish it on SharePoint website. The purpose of the form is for employee to submit request, then the form will be route to 4 different offices for approval.

Here is my form structure:

[Employee Request Details]

[Approval section A]

[Approval section B]

[Approval section C]

[Approval section D]

When the user submit the form, it will trigger the workflow to route the form to different group. Each group will have different group email control by Active Directory. Many people in the same group can access that group email.

My question is how to hide the form from the employee and only make it available to people belong to that specific group? Can Infopath look up Active Directory email group? Or if possible, how to make the approval section visible only for those who receive email from workflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the approval section until the user submits the form. Create a textbox and put a rule in the submit button to increment that text box. So if the textbox equals one, show the approval A, then when approval A submits increment the texbox to show approval b and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Active directory group data with Account Management in code.

Then get current user email from AD with Account Management again.

You can hide approval section with infopath formatting rule if current user email is not in email list.